# Селениум находит элемент, но ничего не возвращает

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Пытаюсь через selenium вытащить текст элемента `div` с классом `asset-name text-truncate`, он выделен:

```
browser.find_elements_by_class_name('asset-name.text-truncate').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Пробовал весь блок взять, типа:

```
browser.find_elements_by_class_name('large-card')
```

И через `xpath`. Он находит элемент, но возвращает пустой список, а должен возвращать текст из элемента. В чем дело и как это исправить? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда должен возвращать?

Comment: @Эникейщик просто в переменную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium не видел элемент, так как те элементы, которые я хотел взять еще не подгрузились java-скриптом. Прописав time.sleep() в пару секунд он нашел их и выдал результат. Было бы здорово, если бы кто-то выложил нормальное решение данной проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать метод `.text` вместо `.get_attribute()`.

Comment: К сожалению, ни тот, ни этот метод не работали. Проблема в том, что страница, которую я парсил автоматически подгружала элементы. Селениум пытался взять то, что еще не появилось